# Is there a way to search the "data-ftjson" tag for the "newreq" portion of an HTML element using Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to find a button on a website that will change based on the date. The button will always have the `"newreq = yes"` identifier present in the "data-ftjson" portion of its element. I need a way to check for this element and then click the button. The screenshot below shows the HTML element of said button. I am using the Selenium WebDriver in Python. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add the class name of your "a" element. In order to get an attribute value, you can use the method "get_attribute("element_name")

```
linkElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'THE CLASS NAME')]")
attributeValue = linkElement.get_attribute("data-ftjson")
stringElement = "\"newreq\":\"yes\""

if (stringElement in attributeValue):
#do something
else:
#do something

#or by json for this you need to import json
jsonValue = attributeValue['newreq']

if jsonValue == 'yes':
    #do something
else:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element where the `data-ftjson` attribute contains `"newreq":"yes"` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'newreq') and contains(., 'yes')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```